# Code inside @available(iOS 13.0, *) doesn't compile in Xcode 10.2 (IOS Swift)

Tags: ios13, xcode10.2.1

I need to implement some NFC reading related code. That is compatible only in iOS 13, say reading NFC tag UID. So, the problem is that I need write the code in a `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` block
and this code is not supported in Xcode 10.2. My project is live and I need to build it using 10.2.
The thing is if I compile the code with Xcode 11 it doesn't give me any error and if I compile it in Xcode 10.2 it gives me this error:

> Use of undeclared type 'NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate'.

Here is the code :

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension myVC: NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate{
    func tagReaderSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession) {
    }

    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
    }

    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
    }
}
```

and all lines of the code is giving the same error as above.

Is there any way to implement this iOS 13 compatible code in Xcode 10?

Comment: Add `import CoreNFC` to your file with extension and the error will disappear